# How to get pre-selected time on 12-hour format Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, time, ionic3

I am trying to get a default value for the time fields on my form. Unfortunately I've had no luck trying to get it working.

.html

```html
      <ion-item class="formField ionField">
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>START TIME</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime
        type="time"
        name="startTime"
        displayFormat="h:mm A"
        pickerFormat="h:mm A"
        minuteValues="0,15,30,45"
        [(ngModel)]="defaultStartTime">
        </ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item class="formField ionField">
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>END TIME</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime
        type="date"
        name="endTime"
        displayFormat="h:mm A"
        minuteValues="0,15,30,45"
        [(ngModel)]="defaultEndTime"></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
```

.ts

```js
defaultStartTime:any = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '5:00 AM').toISOString();
defaultEndTime:any = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '7:00 PM').toISOString();
```

[image: time sample]

This is what it is outputting. I know it has to do with `.getTimezoneOffset();`, but I keep getting errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

```
defaultStartTime: string = new Date(new Date().setHours(5, 0, 0)).toISOString();
defaultEndTime: string = new Date(new Date().setHours(19, 0, 0)).toISOString();
```

[image: updated ScreenShot]

Comment: Just to confirm, you are trying to display the date + time in the template in date + time in AM / PM format?

Comment: No, the date doesn't matter. Unfortunately the form saves the Date in UTC anyways.

Comment: So, is your screenshot the desired output then?

Comment: If you look at the time in my ts code, that's my desired output. The screen shot is what it is displaying.

Comment: Answer coming in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into changing the formatting only at the template level, and not in the component.

Change this:

```
defaultStartTime:any = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '5:00 AM').toISOString();
defaultEndTime:any = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '7:00 PM').toISOString();
```

to this:

```
defaultStartTime: string = new Date(new Date().setHours(5, 0, 0)).toISOString();
defaultEndTime: string = new Date(new Date().setHours(19, 0, 0)).toISOString();
```

And change your template to this:

```
      <ion-item class="formField ionField">
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>START TIME</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime
        type="date"
        name="startTime"
        displayFormat="DDD MMM DD YYYY h:mm A"
        pickerFormat="h:mm A"
        minuteValues="0,15,30,45"
        [(ngModel)]="defaultStartTime">
        </ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item class="formField ionField">
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>END TIME</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime
        type="date"
        name="endTime"
        displayFormat="DDD MMM DD YYYY h:mm A"
        minuteValues="0,15,30,45"
        [(ngModel)]="defaultEndTime"></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
```

More info on the official docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#display-format

Comment: I'm getting this error on the .ts:                                                                          
datetime-util.js:229 Error parsing date: "1542366000183". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format:

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: New Error:    datetime-util.js:229 Error parsing date: "Fri Nov 16 2018 05:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format

Comment: I believe Ionic uses ISO so maybe that's why I'm having such a hard time?

Comment: updating my question with new screen shot. If I remove displayFormat="DDD MMM DD yyyy " i'm back to square one.

Comment: Updated again. Basically, change yyyy to YYYY

Comment: I only need the time display on the form. The time is still off though

Comment: So I changed set hours to .setHours(-1, 0, 0)) and .setHours(13, 0, 0)). It is displaying the correct time now. Thank you very much sir for helping me out with this